# Lightning Web Component Invalid Field Highlight Issue

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have added some controls on LWC component. All fields are required as per requirement. I want to highlight only control not label on submit click. Right now with below code it is highlighting both label as well as control. See attached image.

Is there any syntax for getting only input controls in LWC? I have tried querySelector with input tag but it is not working.

```
  const elements = Array.from(
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input,lightning-input-field,lightning-combobox'),
    );
 elements.forEach((arrayElement, index) => {
    if(elements[index].required && elements[index].value===""){
      elements[index].className = "error";
    }
});
```

[image: Lightning Web Component Invalid Field Issue]

Comment: can you please post a playground link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select the inner components of a component. This is called "CSS isolation", and it prevents you from modifying components this way (see the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom) for more). Instead, you'd use reportValidity or another method to trigger an error state (and have the correct highlights). See [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom) for details.

Comment: Thank You sfdxfox. That's what my question. Is any one done similar to my requirement?

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni No, nobody has, because you can't. This is a feature of LWC.